# How can I get secondary list to populate with json data?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json data file that I am loading into the page and populating some elements dynamically. I also need to populate another select list (#dynamic-zone-list) from the dynamic data and, like I was with the last issue, I'm stuck.

I've tried replicating the js that got me the dynamic data in the first place and I don't get any errors, but the provided code doesn't populate the list. The select shows up, but there's nothing in it and I need to be able to use that select list later on to, again, dynamically change another element.

There's some extra console.log stuff at the top for testing, please disregard that.

#### Javascript

```
// Data Files
const dataFile = "./app/assets/data/schools.json";
const fileInput = fs.readFileSync(dataFile);
const result = JSON.parse(fileInput);

// Important Global variables
const App = $("#App"),
  loadDashboard = "/app/html/dashboards/schooldashboard.html",
  dynamicZoneList = $("#dynamic-zone-list");

function setup() {
  loadJSON("/app/assets/data/schools.json", receivedData);
}

function receivedData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

$.each(result, function(i) {
  var schools = result.schools;

  for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
    console.log(schools[i].id + " " + schools[i].name + " " + schools[i].topic);
  }
});

/////////// This is where I generate the dynamic content. 
/////////// I am trying to generate the second dropdown list here as well. 
///////////The dynamic content in div id="dynamic-school-name" 
///////////populates correctly  

function loadSchools() {
  if (App.hasClass("schoolDash")) {
    var value = menuDropdown.val(),
      zoneOutput = "";
    // get option based on value attribute
    var option = menuDropdown.find('option[value="' + value + '"]');
    var schools = result.schools[option.data("index")];
    $("#dynamic-school-name").html(schools.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
      zoneOutput += "<option>" + schools[i].name + "</option>";
    }
    dynamicZoneList.html(zoneOutput);
  } else {
    App.load(loadDashboard, function() {
      var value = menuDropdown.val(),
        zoneOutput = "";
      // get option based on value attribute
      var option = menuDropdown.find('option[value="' + value + '"]');
      var schools = result.schools[option.data("index")];
      $("#dynamic-school-name").html(schools.name);
      for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
        zoneOutput += "<option>" + schools[i].name + "</option>";
      }
      dynamicZoneList.html(zoneOutput);
      App.addClass("schoolDash");
    });
  }
}

var menuDropdown = $("#schoolDropdown");
var output = "";
var schools = result.schools;
console.log(schools);

for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
  output +=
    '<option value="' +
    schools[i].topic +
    '" data-index="' +
    i +
    '" ' +
    'id="' +
    schools[i].id +
    '" ' +
    'name="dropDownItem' +
    i +
    '">' +
    schools[i].name +
    "</option>";
}

menuDropdown.html(output);

menuDropdown.change(function() {
  loadSchools()
});
```

#### simple html - there's not much there yet and the ids are being populated dynamically

```
<h2 class="dynamic-school-name" id="dynamic-school-name"></h2>
<div class="col-3">
    <select class="dynamic-zone-list" size="100" name="zone-list" id="dynamic-zone-list"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-9">

</div>
```

I would like the select with id=dynamic-zone-list to populate with the data called in function loadSchools(). As I said, I don't get any errors but the data does not load. I think I have done my asynchronous callbacks correctly in loadSchools() but there is still no data. I will be putting different data in later but schools[i].name is data I know I can access easily. Any help in getting the select to populate would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it is because you are using on change is added dynamically is where your problem is. Try: $("body").on("change", menuDropdown, function() {
  loadSchools();
});

Comment: @Icewine solid suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm wondering if maybe the issue is where I'm making the function?

Comment: I went over your code and there are places that the ids dont match up. I dont have the rest of your code that is loaded but $("#schoolDropdown"); I cant find. If i had a more clear picture of what you are trying to do(like a screenshot) then I could help. And maybe a single line of your json format. I am guessing its like : "schools":[
  {"id":"ID 1", "name":"University of Albera", "topic":"0"}, 
  {"id":"ID 2", "name":"University of Tokyo", "topic":"1"},
  {"id":"ID 3", "name":"University of Paris ", "topic":"2"}
]

Comment: $("#schoolDropdown") is declared as var menuDropdown. Here's some json it's test data so nothing too serious:

Comment: ### json ###

    {
  "schools": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "School",
      "topic": "school",
      "address": [
        {
          "street": "123 fake street",
          "city": "faketown",
          "state": "FA",
          "zip": "00000"
        }
      ],

Comment: ### cont. json ###
"phone": "(111) 212-5555",
      "principal": "Mr. Principal",
      "schoolImage": "/assets/images/picture.png",
      "zones": {
        "zoneA": {
          "rooms": [
            "Room 1",
            "Room 2"
          ],
          "image": ""
        },
        "zoneB": {
          "rooms": [
            "Room 101",
            "Room 102"
          ],
          "image": ""
        }
      }
    } //more after this

Comment: Ok, to confirm then, you have 2 drop downs. the first one shows all the school names. The second will show the schools information?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Here's a link to the image https://imgur.com/a/DlKBLS8 I want the white select list on the left of the screen to be filled with the data in loadSchool(), specifically school.zones which will then be used to update some other data on the page.

Comment: So yes, the first one shows the schools names and the second one needs to be filled with the zones from the file based on which school is chosen. The header and the address information is already being filled dynamically.

Comment: Ok, I think i understand now. So lastly to clairify, when you click the blue button up top next to the dashboard button, a list of school names will drop down. Then when you select the school name the data from the chosen school will fill up the empty select box with schoo.zones from the chosen school.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I would like to occur.